# How to maitain thread synchronization with multiple AWS EC2 instances

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, thread-safety

I have specific code which need to be ensured not executed simultaneously for the same user (a use case were user tries to place a specific order from different machines at the same time).

In order to achieve this i have tried thread synchronization which pretty much solved the problem when the code is deployed on a single server.

However i have a query that do i face any issue when the same is executed when having multiple EC2 instances on AWS?

Thread synchronization might not work when requests are propagated to different EC2 instances via load balancer.

Comment: Can you put your FIFO SQS queue to store the job tasks? It guarantee uniqueness within 5 minute window. This way your uses just submit tasks to queue, and at the other end of the queue you have a job dispatcher picking up jobs one-by-one from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people use DynamoDB tables to store states across various worker nodes before.

If you go with this approach just be sure to use [strongly consistent reads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)

Comment: But how do we manage the racing condition from different EC2 instances?